# Trouble Understanding Paramaterized Adjunction Theorem

Tags: category-theory

From pg. 102 of *Categories for the Working Mathematician*:

[image]

Here I understand everything except the red underlined. In particular:

1. Why does uniqueness of conjugates imply that $G(h'h, -) = G(h,-) \circ G(h',-)$?
2. Why does (1) then imply that $G(-,a)$ is a functor and $G$ a bifunctor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The components of the natural transformation $G(h,-)$ can be obtained by applying the commutative square depicted in the proof to $1_{G(p',a)}$ in the bottom right corner with $x=G(p',a)$.

   Double the diagram vertically using maps for $h$ and $h'$. Then $G(h,a)_*\circ G(h',a)_*$ at the right side makes the doubled diagram commutative, but - as $F$ is a bifunctor - on the left side we can transfer concatenation inside $F$, meaning $G(h'h,a)_*=G(h,a)_*\circ G(h',a)_*$.

   Now either apply a Yoneda argument, or apply it directly to $x=G(p'',a)$ as above.
2. Well, as $F$ is a functor, $h=1_p$ implies $G(h,a)=1_{G(p,a)}$ (the commutative square collapses), so $G(-,a)$ respects identity and (reverses) composition, so it is a functor $P^{op}\to X$, by definition. 
   The other part, $G(p,-)$ being a functor $A\to X$ for each object $p$ in $P$ was a hypothesis.